# How can I lock stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: stored-procedures

How can I lock my stored procedure so that users cannot modify, but users can see it?

Like this: some stored procedure is locked for all users, and some is unlock.

Like this image

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G99qk.png

Comment: Crazy idea: Permissions?

Comment: Please See the Linked Image

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/

Comment: in this image , stored procedure is not encrypt , just i can't modify, please help me

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.enc_sp
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
 --here is your query
```

based on
[this answer](https://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/03/07/decrypting-encrypted-stored-procedures-views-functions-in-sql-server-20052008-r2/)